# How to config computer/phone network to access local web server via USB (Android:GAE)?

Tags: android, google-app-engine, networking

Current configuration

Use Android emulator and GAE tools 
(to access local GAE service I set uri http://10.0.2.2:8888/XXX and it works.

Question

I would like to use Android device(phone) via USB to call web service running on connected "local" computer. 
What is best configuration practice ((I don't have static IP) I am using mac and linux)?

Answer (score 2):

If you can connect both the local computer and your phone to the same wireless network, you could just access your PC from your phone by the IP address of the computer's wifi interface.